# jsf tags can not be parsed on hosting server

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

the issue is when i run my jsf application on local server it runs without any issues... but when i my application on hosting server the jsf tags are not parsed....

my url pattern is

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>faces/index1.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

in my local server if i'm give http://localhost:8080/applicationname ,it directly redirect to my index page. the application works fine ...

But in the hosting server the below url returns "request resource not found"

```
http://domainname/applicationname/
http://domainname/applicationname/faces/index.xhtml
```

But if give the url name without faces then the content works,not jsf functionality(jsf tags not parsed)...

```
http://domainname/applicationname/index.xhtml
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Add jsf jars to the hosting server and make sure they are in the class path just like in your local environment

Answer (score 1):

Add jsf jars to the hosting server and make sure they are in the class path just like in your local environment and make sure the right web.xml is in use...

Comment: double check that you are using the right web.xml (for example , delete the web.xml and see if the web server still works... then put it back...), cause if it worked on local it should work on the other server too,

Comment: i delete the web.xml in my eclipse environment... now the static content only worked..not jsf

Comment: why at your local eclipe ? You said that the issues are at the hosting server... you should do the checks in your hosting server...